# Graph Bi-partition - Normalized cuts

Tags: math, graph-theory

Can anyone explain me how to do cut in graph in the Normalized cuts algorithm descriped here: http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~bai/ECS231/returnsfinal/WangH.pdf (page 3 bottom)?

I have image, graph, solved eigenvalue problem, eigenvector of 2nd smallest eigenvalue. But I don't know how to cut graph.

Comment: It appears that the cut algorithm is precisely where you pointed us. What don't you understand?

Comment: I dont understand how to cut graph with knowledge of vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to 'cut' the graph. All you need to do is split the current image in 2 sets, `A` and `B` with `A = y_1(i) > t` and `B = y_1(i) <= t` where `y_1` refering to your algorithm is the second smallest eigenvector (also the solution for normalized cuts, stated in proposition 2) and `t` as the section 4.4 of the paper explains could be 0, mean, median, mode or the value of your choice, with different results as shown in section 5.

You only need the indexes of where that happens, as if they were 2 different binary masks for your original image. Then the `ncut_partitions` algorithm recursively calls itself with both `A` and `B` sets separately as the new images.

Follow "Algorithm 1 Recursive two-way cut" line by line.

Comment: can you give me explaning example? what is y_1 i and t? Now I have degree matrix, weight matrix a img matrix and nodes of graph.

Comment: I've edited a bit the answer. As the proposition 2 of the paper stays, y_1 is the solution to the NCuts and also the second smallest eigenvector. Then y_1 is used to mask the image, separating whenever y_1 is smaller or larget than a predefined threshold. The threshold as stated in section 4.4 could be 0, median, mean or mode value or y_1, as you wish (with different results as shown in section 5).

Comment: I dont understand the equation y_1(i)<=t. y_1 is vector and i is point I guess. For example when y_1=(-3,2) then (-3i_1, 2i_2)<=t. Still its point, no real value as t is.

Comment: Sorry the late reply, `i` is the index. The `D` matrix is a diagonal matrix with the image in the diagonal. When you calculate the second smallest eigenvector (`y_1` in the paper) it has size `N` where `N = cols x rows` of your image. Therefore you can reshape the eigenvector to be as the image, and then you can separate each pixel of the image considering the value of `y_1` at that position.